# Enter hours worked Python program

Tags: python, python-3.x

The problem:

> Write a program which asks the user to enter an integer 'n' which
> would be the total numbers of hours the user worked in a week and
> calculates and prints the total amount of money the user made during
> that week. If the user enters any number less than 0 or greater than
> 168 (n < 0 or n > 168) then your program should print INVALID
>
> Assume that hourly rate for the first 40 hours is $8 per hour.
>
> Hourly rate for extra hours between 41 and 50 (41 <= n <= 50 ) is $9
> per hour.
>
> Hourly rate for extra hours greater than 50 is $10 per hour.
>
> Here are a few examples:
>
> if the user enters -5, then your program should print  INVALID
>
> if the user enters 34, then your program should print  YOU MADE 272
> DOLLARS THIS WEEK
>
> if the user enters 45, then your program should print  YOU MADE 365
> DOLLARS THIS WEEK
>
> if the user enters 67, then your program should print  YOU MADE 580
> DOLLARS THIS WEEK
>
> Note that the amount of money made by the user must be an integer (not
> a float) and your output should exactly match the format specified
> above (including spaces and capitalization).

My code:

```
hours = int(input("how many hours did you work this week? "))

if hours  < 0 or > 168:

    print ("INVALID")

elif hours  <= 40

    Rate = $8

elif hours (<= 41 or <= 50)

    Rate = $9

elif hours >= 50

    Rate = $10
```

I know it's not done yet but I don't know what to do as next and I can't fix the syntax problem.

Comment: That's not even nearly Python code. You need a structured tutorial, see e.g. https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F.

Answer (score 2):

```
if hours  < 0 or > 168:
```

is incorrect
referring to [Why does `a == b or c or d` always evaluate to True?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-b-or-c-or-d-always-evaluate-to-true)

This is a right way to write this statement:

```
if hours < 0 or hours > 168:
```

Furthermore, the following is also incorrect:

```
elif hours (<=41 or <=50)
```

This statement will only be reached if hours <= 40 thus you can omit checking if hours <= 41 in the incorrect statement.

The following will work right:

```
elif hours <= 50:
```

(don't forget `:` even with elif statements)

Comment: great explanation as a new contributor. Can I recommend that you also summarize the answer for OP with the correct full code. That way, they can see how it all fits together.

Answer (score 0):

CODE:

```
import sys

hours = int(input("how many hours did you work this week? "))

if hours  < 0 or hours > 168:
    print("invalid")
    #here i used sys.exit so that it can exit after printing invalid
    sys.exit()
elif hours  <= 40 and hours > 0:
    a = hours
    b = 0
    c = 0 
elif hours>40 and hours <= 50:
    a = 40
    b = (hours - a)
    c = 0
elif hours > 50:
    a = 40
    b = 10
    c = hours - (a+b)

rate = (a*8)+(b*9)+(c*10)
print("\n\nYOU MADE {} DOLLARS THIS WEEK".format(rate))
```

OUTPUT 1:

```
how many hours did you work this week? 34

YOU MADE 272 DOLLARS THIS WEEK
```

OUTPUT 2:

```
how many hours did you work this week? 67

YOU MADE 580 DOLLARS THIS WEEK
```

Comment: thank you guys, i just started to code a few days ago so i have to learn alot before i understand the logic after all of that.

Answer (score 0):

I myself has just started learning Python and spent hours looking for a solution of this quiz

@Alpha Green's method help but in the end answer was wrong.

This is what i did which was accepted

```
    user_entry=int(input("Enter total numbers of hours worked this week "))
    r = user_entry
    s = 0
    t = 0
    if user_entry <0 or user_entry >168 :
        print("INVALID")
    if user_entry <=40 and user_entry >=0 :
        r
        print("YOU MADE",r * 8,"DOLLARS THIS WEEK")
    if user_entry > 40 and user_entry <= 50 :
        r = 40
        s = (user_entry - r)
        print("YOU MADE",(r*8)+(s*9),"DOLLARS THIS WEEK")
    if user_entry >50 and user_entry <=168:
        r = 40
        s = 10
        t=user_entry - (r + s)
        amount=(r * 8) + (s * 9) + (t * 10)

        print("YOU MADE",amount,"DOLLARS THIS WEEK")
```

OUTPUT # 1

```
    Enter total numbers of hours worked this week 34
    YOU MADE 272 DOLLARS THIS WEEK
```

OUTPUT # 2

```
    Enter total numbers of hours worked this week 67
    YOU MADE 580 DOLLARS THIS WEEK
```

OUTPUT # 3

```
    Enter total numbers of hours worked this week -2
    INVALID
```

Comment: There's an unnecessary r when the input is between 0 and 40!